# Facing issue while running through DB link

Tags: sql, oracle, dblink

Facing issue in executing query through DB link, If i am running same query directly in destination database it is taking 30 seconds at max. But through DBlink it is gling in long running session ans creating multiple sessions.

```sql
select distinct adj.account_num,cpad.attribute_value as SERVICE_ID_GENEVA,adj.adjustment_txt,adj.adjustment_net_mny/1000 as ADJ_AMT 
from geneva_Admin.adjustment@IRASDB_GENEVADB adj, 
     geneva_Admin.custproductattrdetails@IRASDB_GENEVADB cpad, 
     geneva_Admin.custproductdetails@IRASDB_GENEVADB cpd 
where cpad.customer_ref=cpd.customer_ref 
  and cpad.product_seq=cpd.product_seq 
  and cpd.account_num=adj.account_num 
  and cpad.attribute_value in (select distinct cpad.attribute_value 
                               from  geneva_Admin.custproductattrdetails@IRASDB_GENEVADB cpad, 
                                     geneva_Admin.custoverrideprice@IRASDB_GENEVADB cop 
                               where cpad.customer_ref=cop.customer_ref 
                                 and cpad.product_seq=cop.product_seq 
                                 and cop.recurring_number>0 
                                 and cpad.attribute_value in (select SERVICEID_BPM from BPM_SFDC_common_data)) 
   and adj.adjustment_txt LIKE ('%'||cpad.attribute_value||'%')
   and adj.adjustment_type_id=201
```

Comment: Can you share your error or explain query or table structure so that user can help you better.

Comment: try creating a view on your destination database and select that view through your database link

Comment: All the tables of the query use dblink except one. Try using the DRIVING_SITE hint to tell your DB to 'execute the query on the other site'